# Can't unzip file after download php

Tags: php, wordpress, zip, wordpress-theming

Hello guys im created a function to create zip file for me and download it
but when i import the file it's can't unzip my file i don't know and here is a picture
of file created by php and manualy to see the differents

[image]

**here is my code:**

```
      $zip = new ZipArchive;
      $zip_name = 'test.zip';
      if ($zip->open($zip_name, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE)
      {
       
          $zip->addFile('1.csv', 'demofile/1.csv');
          $zip->addFile('2.csv', 'demofile/2.csv');
          $zip->addFile('1.csv', 'demofile2/1.json');
    

          $zip->addFromString('demofile/1.csv', $content_1);
          $zip->addFromString('demofile/2.csv', $content_2);
          $zip->addFromString('demofile2/1.json', $contents);
          // All files are added, so close the zip file.
          $zip->close();

          header('Content-type: application/zip');
          header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
          header("Content-length: ".filesize($zip_name));

          readfile($zip_name);

          exit();
      }
```

Comment: Try opening the zip file with a desktop tool, I’m guessing it will say it is corrupt. Also try opening the zip file in a text tool such as notepad on Windows. If you see any human-readable text, there’s a good chance some HTTP output, possibly a header or a PHP warning, is getting added to the beginning or end.

Comment: yes you are right i see human-readable text but only the folder names `PK   E8ÎT°¡Æ"   $      demo_folder/new.txt+I­(Q(ÉWHJUHLIIM±K2RòRËõJ€Ri™9© PK   |ÑT6À¸¶   ]  ` so you mean it's an php error has been added so that why the zip file is not working?

Comment: PHP errors are the first thing to check for, but what you quoted does not look like a PHP error message, rather normal zip file content. What happens when you store your generated zip file to the server's HDD and then download it from there afterwards, manually - same result?

Comment: When i generated zip by my self manually and upload it to unzip with php it works well, but when PHP generated zip file and when i try to upload it its gives me error and says unzip is failed or couldnt to extract the zip file

Comment: Creating the zip file manually with a desktop program and having it work proves that the system that is accepting the zip file is probably working correctly. Now, take the server-generated zip file and try opening it with a desktop software of some sort. Be careful that you acquire the file from the server for testing purposes in the same way that is causing the problem. It is possible that the zip is correct, but the transfer has something extra.